# Exact way to switch to websocket connection after successful http request (response 101)?

Tags: python, http, websocket, python-requests, wss

I'm trying to connect to WebSocket using python but confused about the exact process of transition to make websocket connection work.

So far, I've succeeded in making http "upgrade" request using requests package and got 101 response from the server.

The code looks like this

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'lang': 'en',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.2001593629.1610867666',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.1826988459.1610867666',
    '_gat_UA-171812727-1': '1',
    '_ym_uid': '1610867667240953916',
    '_ym_d': '1610867667',
    '_ym_visorc_65463124': 'w',
    '_ym_isad': '2',
    '_gat_UA-171812727-2': '1',
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'ws.website.com',
    'Connection': 'Upgrade',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
    'Upgrade': 'websocket',
    'Origin': 'https://website.com',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'FMZPo/xOQ3NdTAIkH2hJaw==',
}

response = requests.get('https://ws.website.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, verify=False)

print(response.status_code)  # prints 101
```

The point of confusion is that when I check Chrome's network tab under WS I see that request URL in headers is wss://ws.website.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket. When trying to use wss scheme in request.get() I get 400 response.

So should I use http scheme when making upgrade requests and use requests package or I have to use another package like websocket and make request starting with wss://??

Is there a correct way to proceed with websocket connection after the part of the code I provided?

Your help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Any reason you are not using a websocket client library like [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)?

Comment: I tried to use websockets library using create_connection method (supplying wss://ws.website.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket request URL, header and cookie parameters) but keep getting 400 response.